# Update existing rows with squence number/char or any unique data

Tags: sql-server

I added a new column in the Table X

This column "cn" has to be unique and mandatory, but old data don't have any value.

How to update the existing records with sequecely or random unique data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though I think you've created the column already, in this answer I'm going on the assumption that the column does not yet exist. IMO, a unique required column should *never* be added without planning how to populate the existing rows first. Therefore, I will provide the methods to do this starting from zero.

---

How you do this depends on what is involved in populating the values.

After whichever method you use, add an unique constraint on the column to ensure data integrity. For Methods 1 and 2, this can be done within the single statement or within a user transaction (not shown), and should be done within the user transaction in Method 3.

There are probably a few other obscure ways of doing this, but I think I've covered the most common.

---

**Method 1: Add an IDENTITY column**

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn int IDENTITY(1, 2) NOT NULL
```

This will populate all rows in the table with integer values starting with the seed value (1), increasing by the increment value (2) for every row. I believe the order the values get populated is undefined (if you have to specify an order, use Method 3).

---

**Method 2: Populate using a default constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyColumn
        DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID())
```

This will do three things atomically: 1. Add a column that does not allow `NULL` values; 2. Create a default constraint for the column; 3. Populate each row in the table using the default constraint.

While this example uses a `uniqueidentifier` column, it works just as well with any data type and default constraint.

---

**Method 3: Populate using an UPDATE statement**

This case would occur when, for example, there was a value from another part of your application that needs to be added to the table, or you need to specify an exact order for the unique values.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn int NULL

    UPDATE MyTable
        SET MyColumn = ...

    ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn int NOT NULL

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

---

**Method 4: Populate using a SEQUENCE object**

For SQL Server 2012, you can populate a column using values generated by a `SEQUENCE` object -- I haven't worked with this at all yet, so I will refer to [a MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx) for completeness.

Comment: Thank you all, I used the method 3 with a combination with the first answer : update T
set cn = rn
from (
       select cn,
              row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
       from TableX
     ) T

Comment: Example of using sequence (assuming you have a sequence called mysequence): `update mytable set mycolumn = next value for mysequence where mycolumn is null;`

Answer (score 14):

If you are happy with a number starting from 1 you can use `row_number()`.

```
update T
set cn = rn
from (
       select cn,
              row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
       from TableX
     ) T
```

Answer (score 11):

The following updates column 'cn' with sequence number starting from 1

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE X
SET @id = cn = @id + 1 
GO
```

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1467/populate-a-sql-server-column-with-a-sequential-number-not-using-an-identity/

Answer (score 1):

try this to update using a sequence... You have to do the TOP because of the order by clause in the update statement. I used this statement on SQL SERVER 2012

```
update invoice set RecNo = (next value for seq_invoice_recno)
where invoiceid in (select top 100000 invoiceid from invoice where RecNo is null 
order by invoiceId)
```

Answer (score -1):

And if all of this still won't work (maybe because it's plain old SQL-92), you can break this down into multiple steps, as suggested by Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister, [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135213/very-tricky-cant-update-a-sequential-list-sql-92-filemaker).

```
CREATE TABLE sorting (sid numeric(10,10), rn int);

INSERT INTO sorting (sid, rn)
SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
ORDER BY SortID;

UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = (SELECT rn FROM sorting WHERE sid=Beleg.SortID)
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210;

DROP TABLE sorting;
```

Comment: What is this `RecordNumber`? Seems like a proprietary Filemaker function/feature. Doesn't apply to SQL Server and not in SQL 92 standard.

Comment: Yes, you're right. RecordNumber is a calculated column that you can define in Filemaker, that holds the record number of each row when it is displayed on screen and after it is sorted (by Filemaker).

Comment: OK, good, didn't know that. But the question here is not tagged with `Filemaker` so I don't think the answer is relevant. You could use a temp table and fill that column with `ROW_NUMBER()` function though.