# Very tricky: Can't update a sequential list SQL-92 ( Filemaker)

Tags: update, sorting, filemaker

I have a quite simple problem, but the solution is very tricky. I'm trying to solve this for months:

There is a column "SortID" that needs to get updated with sequential integers, starting from 1. The column may look like this (without ORDER BY):

```
SELECT SortID FROM Beleg

2
3
.5
4
5
9
10
10.000001
10.000002
11
13
```

and needs to look like this.

```
2
3
1
4
5
6
7
8
… and so on
```

I have tried everything that I can think of, but no luck.

I am using the Execute SQL function from within Filemaker and I can just use plain SQL-92, nothing fancy.

For example, the following tricks all don't work (for example: [Update existing rows with sequence number…](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/update-existing-rows-with-squence-number-char-or-any-unique-data)). All produce syntax errors:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn int IDENTITY(1, 2) NOT NULL
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyColumn
        DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID())
```

and (no variables allowed):

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE X
SET @id = cn = @id + 1 
GO
```

and (ROW_NUMBER () doesn't work):

```
update T
set cn = rn
from (
    select cn,
        row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
    from TableX
    ) T
```

and (this gets close, but no):

```
update invoice set RecNo = (next value for seq_invoice_recno)
where invoiceid in (select top 100000 invoiceid from invoice where RecNo is null 
order by invoiceId)
```

. . .
However, I have come a little closer: I can use a Filemaker function "RecordNumber" that returns a sequential number for each line. Using this statement, I can get the correct order and get the correct integer for that line:

```
SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
ORDER BY SortID

.5  1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
10.00001    11
10.00002    12
```

But when I try to write the values, I get an error, as soon as include the ORDER BY statement:

```
UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = RecordNumber
WHERE YEAR ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
ORDER BY SortID
```

=> ERROR

Only, when I remove the ORDER BY, the values are written — but in the wrong order!

```
UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = RecordNumber
WHERE YEAR ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
… and so on
```

The SortID "1" should have been written into line 3 and the "2" into the first line, the "3" into the second line, like this:

```
2
3
1
4
5
6
7
8
… and so on
```

So close, but still no luck.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another approach, which, however, is likely to perform worse than [the other suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135237/6965):

```
UPDATE
  Beleg
SET
  SortID = (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      Beleg AS Beleg2
    WHERE
      Year ( Beleg2.Valuta ) = Year ( Beleg.Valuta )
      AND Beleg2.Ursprungskonto = Beleg.Ursprungskonto
      AND Beleg2.SortID <= Beleg.SortID
  )
WHERE
  Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
  AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
;
```

On the plus side, not only does this method reset *SortID* values in a single step, it can also do that for multiple *(Year(Valuta), Ursprungskonto)* subsets at once, if need be. That is, you can specify multiple values for either attribute in the main WHERE clause, e.g. like this:

```
WHERE
  Year ( Valuta ) BETWEEN 2011 AND 2016
  AND Ursprungskonto IN (1210, 2101, 1012)
```

or even just remove the WHERE clause altogether – and each subset will be re-numerated separately from the others, all with the single query.

Important note: this method assumes that *SortID* values are unique across any single *(Year(Valuta), Ursprungskonto)* subset.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to create a table, and update allows you to use the result of a subselect (all valid SQL92 code), you should be able do perform the following multi-step process:

```
CREATE TABLE sorting (sid numeric(10,10), rn int);

INSERT INTO sorting (sid, rn)
SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
ORDER BY SortID;

UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = (SELECT rn FROM sorting WHERE sid=Beleg.SortID)
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210;

DROP TABLE sorting;
```

You may need to cast rn to numeric, or use a datatype other than numeric (such as `double precision`).